# Remove Object From Array Using Enumeration

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enumeration

I have an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains latitude and longitude so I'm getting the distance of each item from the current user location. If the distance in miles is greater than 20, that particular dictionary should be removed from the array. If the dictionary is not removed from the array, an annotation is created  and added to an annotation array which is then used to add annotations to a map once the enumeration is finished. I'm only getting one annotation added when I should be getting three so I know I'm doing something wrong in my enumeration.

```
func checkDistanceAndAddPins() {
        for gym in gyms {
            var index = 0

            let gymLatitude = gym["latitude"]!!.doubleValue
            let gymLongitude = gym["longitude"]!!.doubleValue
            let gymLocation = CLLocation(latitude: gymLatitude, longitude: gymLongitude)
            let distance = gymLocation.distanceFromLocation(myLocation!)
            let distanceInMeters = NSNumber(double: distance)
            let metersDouble = distanceInMeters.doubleValue
            let miles = metersDouble * 0.00062137

            if miles > maxDistance {
                gyms.removeAtIndex(index)
            } else {
                let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: gymLatitude, longitude: gymLongitude)
                gymAnnotation.title = gym["Name"] as? String
                gymAnnotation.subtitle = gym["Address"] as? String
                gymAnnotation.coordinate = location
                gymAnnotation.gymPhoneNumber = gym["Phone"] as? String
                if let website = gym["Website"] as? String {
                    gymAnnotation.gymWebsite = website
                }
                gymLocations.append(gymAnnotation)
            }

            index += 1
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.gymMap.addAnnotations(self.gymLocations)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you declare `gymAnnotation`? Guess you should initialise a new one in the `for` loop. Not outside of the for scope. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thanks.